# Changing default message displayed after execution of Katalon Studio test cases

Tags: testing, automated-tests, reporting, katalon-studio

Is it possible to change the default message that is displayed after the test case execution?

I would like to 'translate' technical terms to the user-friendly ones. So that people running the tests could interpret the results without knowing the details of the script. The problem is when a customer service employee runs a test and gets a message saying something like: "Test failed because [*error stack trace*]" they don't know how to interpret it.

Comment: Why don't you use description for testcases?

Comment: You can use custom assertion at the end of the test and print a customized, non-technical text message to report.

Comment: OK, that's what I'm trying to figure out how to do. How do I print a custom message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use solution below to show personalized messages in case of failure.

```
if(!WebUI.verifyElementClickable(findTestObject('abc/button_next'), FailureHandling.OPTIONAL)){
   KeywordUtil.markFailedAndStop("Failed to found button on page!")
}
```